# C# System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' When using MySQL with Discord.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, discord.net

I've been getting errors which are terrible :D

```
        public static List<tableName> GetUserStatus(IUser user)
    {
        var result = new List<tableName>();

        var database = new Database("dibot");

        var str = string.Format("SELECT * FROM dibott WHERE userid = '{0}'", user.Id);
        var tableName = database.FireCommand(str);

        while (tableName.Read())
        {
            var userId = (string)tableName["userid"];
            var userName = (string)tableName["username"];
            var currentTokens = (int)tableName["tokens"]; // Here

            result.Add(new tableName
            {
                userid = userId,
                username = userName,
                tokens = currentTokens
            });
        }
        database.CloseConnection();

        return result;

    }
```

At this command

```
        [Command("Status")]
    [Alias("status", "s")]
    public async Task Status([Remainder] IUser user = null)
    {
        var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        {
            Color = new Color(0, 0, 255)
        };
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = Context.User;
        }

        var result = Database.CheckExistingUser(user); //Here

        if (result.Count() <= 0)
        {
            Database.EnterUser(user);
        }

        var tableName = Database.GetUserStatus(user);
```

I've tried everything please help.
I tried much things.
Nothing helped
Asking for help because im out of ideas and in internet there arent any fixes
I've put // To see where are the errors. I hope i get helped soon! :)

Comment: whats tokens column type?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Steve The token's column type is varchar(50)

Answer (score 2):

So the problematic line is this:

```
var currentTokens = (int)tableName["tokens"];
```

`InvalidCastException` means that the type contained in `tableName["tokens"]` is **not** `int`. To get at the actual type you can for example remove the cast, put a breakpoint on that line and check with the debugger.

From your comment we know that the database type is a varchar, which means you need to use string in .NET:

```
var currentTokens = (string)tableName["tokens"];
```

Comment: If it is that, that sounds like pretty bad DB design. String as a Primary key is not a good type. And if you expected Integer at this point, it propably could be a interger at that point.

Comment: @Christopher: From what I guessed this could be the schema used by [discordapp](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user), which uses Twitter's [snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake/tree/snowflake-2010) type. This type is probably represented as a string in the .NET api.

Comment: The int.Parse isn't working. I'm trying with GetType but not giving any good results.

Answer (score 0):

since you are casting tokens into `int` im assuming its a numeric column.

If you have `TINYINT` then use `byte`, if its unsigned then use `ubyte`
if you have `SMALLINT` then use `short`, or `ushort` if its unsigned
if you have `MEDIUMINT/INT` then use `int` or `uint` for unsigned
if you have `BIGINT` then use `long` or `ulong` for unsigned

best way to find out is to do a `tableName["tokens"].GetType()`.

If you don't cast it to the right type you will get that `InvalidCast` exception

Edit:

Based on your comment its a `varchar` column which means its a string. if you want to make it an int then you need to do

```
int.Parse((string) tableName["tokens"]);
```

or

```
long.Parse((string) tableName["tokens"]);
```

if its a 64 bit int

But it is really a bad design to store numeric in string format and later on parse it again.